# How to convert vowels in words to leet using python?

Tags: python

I need to convert the vowels of words into leet in a function. I used the suggestion from an old post from Stack Overflow using tuples for all the vowels like `('a', '4')`, etc. and the `.replace()` method and it worked with all the sample words except `'Academy'` because it didn't account for the capital `'A'`. I have tried so many ways to get it right and I can't get it! I'm a beginner at Python and I'm sure I'm missing something so obvious. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Try converting all the words to lowercase first using `'Academy'.lower()`.

Comment: You should include some of the code you've tried as an example. That way folks have some better idea of how to help you.

Comment: You say you "have tried so many ways to get it right", but you're not sharing what you expected to work and are basically just asking people on SO to solve this trivial problem for you - please give it an honest try and then come here to ask why something you expect to work doesn't.

Comment: How long you've spent on it is really quite immaterial to the question. It really is required that you make the task of answering your question as easy as possible. It isn't so much lazy as rude... (sorry for the harsh feedback).

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe create a list of the vowels you're searching for:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

for vowel in vowels:
    if vowel in your_string:
        your_string = your_string.replace(vowel, ...)  # find the leet values like you currently do instead of ...
```

Then if anything in the list of vowels is found in your string (for example, Academy) then replace the letter with the leet.

Comment: Perhaps because you're answering a half-assed question instead of helping the OP develop their question into something more sensible. Additionally, your answer is a single line of code without any explanation of how to use it (you could guess what the OP is doing, or ask them to improve their question with the code they're using), nor any explanation of why this will work when the OP's code isn't working (same parenthetical as before). If you provided fully functional code with input, output, and explanation I would have upvoted.

Comment: OP didn't offer what she specifically wanted, and she didn't provide her own code either. I just provided a solution to her problem that could work if she implemented it into her own code. And I wouldn't know how to improve the question anyways; I don't know exactly what she wants.

Comment: How do you know that your solution would "work if she implemented it into her own code" when you don't know what their code is. You can help OP improve the question by making them state exactly what they want. Regardless, your text, as it currently stands, is not an answer (it could be useful as a comment).

Comment: better? And I can't exactly force her to state whatever she wants, but I can help her as much as I can.

Comment: Thanks, Rebecca. I don't have access to the work I already did and I didn't have time to recreate it. I'm just frustrated, and kind of sorry I asked. These guys are brutal. Thanks for being nice. I'll probably delete the question.